# Секундомер Java (Stopwatch Java);

Tags: java

Нужно написать графический секундомер на Java. 
Графику уже отрисовал, а вот с самим устройством работы секундомера вопросы:
1) Какие готовые классы лучше всего для этого использовать?
Стоит ли для расчета времени воспользоваться классом `Date`, а далее сохранить дату запуска секундомера и далее каждую секунду Отнимать разница между текущей датой и сохраненной ?
2) Будет ли описанный метод рациональным если я так же захочу выводить и миллисекунды ?

Comment: Java не гарантирует время ответа. Так что если вам нужно замерять время очень точно, то java не подходит.

Comment: зачем изобретать велосипед?

Answer (score 1):

```
@SuppressWarnings ("serial")
public class TimerLabel extends JLabel
{
    public TimerLabel (Timer timer)
    {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    }

    private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        private volatile int time = -1;

        private Runnable refresher = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                int t = time;
                TimerLabel.this.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", t / 60, t % 60));
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            time++;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(refresher);
        }
    };

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel timerLabel = new TimerLabel(new Timer());
        timerLabel.setFont(new Font(timerLabel.getFont().getFontName(), timerLabel.getFont().getStyle(), 36));
        frame.add(timerLabel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

попробуйте? возможно просто расширите функционал и будет все гуд)